# PHP MySQL utf 8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

My trying to make an Ajax call to a PHP function that pulls out data from my database. I've run into a problem though.

My query looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field LIKE '%$string%'"
```

I then check on the number of rows returned by the query, but when i type in æ ø å then i my query returns 0 rows, although I know there are entries in the database that have æ ø å.. why is this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set the connection to use UTF-8:

```
<?php

// MySQLi:

$connection = new MySQLi( /* ... credentials ...*/);
$connection->set_charset("utf8");


// MySQL:
$connection = mysql_connect(/* ... credentials ... */); 
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $connection);

?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the correct collation for your tables, too!

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I had to add this line:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8mb4");
```