# Getting question marks instead of Hebrew while using PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, hebrew

I'm connecting to MySQL with PHP, fetching Hebrew results, and getting question marks instead of Herbew letters.

I know it may be duplicated, but I did whatever needed from anywhere in the internet ([including here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287821/mysql-db-question-marks-instead-of-hebrew-characters)) but I got nothing.

1. The relevant columns is with CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci.
2. I did add the relevant Headers on top of the PHP code:

   HEADERS (header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); )
3. I did add the Meta tags under the "Head" tag:
4. I did add the relevant SET-NAMES call before connecting:

   mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");

If it helps, when querying the database using Workbench /J, I do get Hebrew results.
However, on PHP...still...getting question marks.

Any idea what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL utf 8 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610254/php-mysql-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 5):

Ho...just found a question in anoher post about general Encoding:
[PHP MySQL utf 8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610254/php-mysql-utf-8-encoding).

Just need to add:
$connect->set_charset("utf8");

I'm not deleting this question since it may help some guys in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!, This is how it looks and now working: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");